# Taking a Selfie, using HappyFunTimes & Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, html, unity-game-engine

I'm currently using the **HappyFunTimes** asset for a game I'm making in Unity. I've been trying to access the players camera on their phone in order to take a selfie and display it on the tv. So far I have this, but I'm having trouble converting the **HTML input type File to a Unity UI Image**. This is what I've got so far

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PlayerPicture</title>
<script src = "hft/hft.js"></script>
<script type =text/javascript">
    var client= new hft.GameClient();
    function submitDrawing(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000"; //to help tell if button is pressed
        var picture = document.getElementById("myImage");
        client.sendCMD('sendPic', {playerpicture: picture});
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id = "PictureTaken">
<input type = "file" id = "myImage" accept = "image/*"/>
<input type = "submit" value= "Submit" onclick = "submitDrawing()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
class PlayerPicture{
    public Image playerPicture; //I don't know what type this data should be
}

public class TakePicture: MonoBehaviour {
    private HFTInput m_input;
    private HFTGamepad m_gamepad;
    private NetPlayer m_netPlayer;
    public Image playerPicture;

    private void Start(){
        m_input = GetComponent<HFTInput>();
        m_gamepad = GetComponent<HFTGamepad>();
    }

    void InitializeNetPlayer(SpawnInfo spawninfo){
        m_netPlayer = spawnInfo.netPlayer;
        m_netPlayer.RegisterCmdHandler<PlayerPicture>("sendPic", SetPicture);
    }
    void SetPicture(PlayerPicture data){
        //convert data to image here
        Debug.Log(data.playerPicture.name);
    }
```

}

I've looked into converting it the file through `.toDataUrl();` but I don't know what to do from there. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code as text within your question, not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it is to get the image, then I draw it into a canvas tag, I get a dataURL from the canvas tag and send that to Unity

### HTML

```html
    <div id="picture">
      <label>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*">
        take picture
      </label>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```css
#picture input[type=file] {
    display: none;
}
#picture label {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

### JavaScript

Note I thought it was best to send a smaller image. The code scales the image to 256x256 using a [css cover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) style algorithm

```js
var picFrameElem = document.getElementById("picture");
var picElem = document.querySelector("#picture input[type=file]");

// Send selected picture to game
picElem.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    // NOTE: Older iOS could not handle camera images
    // in web pages
    picFrameElem.style.display = "none";
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = 256;
      canvas.height = 256;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var aspect = img.width / img.height;
      var dstHeight = 256
      var dstWidth = dstHeight * aspect;
      if (dstWidth < 256) {
        dstWidth = 256;
        dstHeight = dstWidth / aspect;
      }
      var dstX = (256 - dstWidth) / 2;
      var dstY = (256 - dstHeight) / 2;
      ctx.drawImage(img, dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
      client.sendCmd('pic', {
        dataUrl: canvas.toDataURL(),
      });
      URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  }
});
```

The `<label>` lets me hide the standard `<input>` UI

Then in Unity I setup a message handler to receive the data

### C#

```cs
private class MessagePic {
    public string dataUrl;
}

void InitializeNetPlayer(SpawnInfo spawnInfo) {
    ...
    m_netPlayer.RegisterCmdHandler<MessagePic>("pic", OnPicture);
    ...
}

void SetTexture(Byte[] binaryData)
{
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(4, 4);
    tex.LoadImage(binaryData);
    m_renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
    m_renderer.material.color = Color.white;
}

private static string s_dataUrlHeader = "data:image/png;base64,";

private void OnPicture(MessagePic data) {
    SetTexture(Convert.FromBase64String(data.dataUrl.Substring(s_dataUrlHeader.Length)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!   I got the phone to connect to the client, but  I can't get the picElem.addEventListener('change', function(event){...} part to run. I cant tell if there is a compile error or if its not detecting a change.

Comment: Have you learned about remote debugging? Both Safari (iOS) and Chrome (Android) will let you debug a webpage over USB from Safari (Mac) and Chrome (Windows/Mac/Linux)